# Why getting 401 when trying validating Token

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, jwt, token

I have a Bearer token and need to validate it against a api and validateToken endpoint. The endpoint aspects a json like that:

```
{
  "jwtToken": "my token"
}
```

At the swagger I try successful this endpoint using url 
http://10.212.226.31:5022/api/v1/validateToken

But I need to validate from code and there I get a 401 'Unauthorized'.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.212.226.31:5022/")
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string token = accessToken.Replace("Bearer ", "");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
    "api/v1/validateToken", token);
```

At the response object I get the 401.

What is wrong? Some thing about the json?
How to hand over the right stuff to the endpoint?

---

Additions:

I work remote on a virtual machine from a costumer and he does not allow installing software. Fiddler and co is not available.

I tried also this, but it's not working:

```
ValidateTokenRequest tokenJson = new ValidateTokenRequest
{
    jwtToken = token
};
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
    "api/v1/validateToken", tokenJson);
```

Comment: Try to pass token as json or some object instead of a string when you call PostAsJsonAsync.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture first request using swagger.  Then compare with first request using C# app.  You need to modify a header in the c# client.  I suspect it may be the Content-Type which indicated the default browses to use.

Comment: Does your "api/v1/validateToken" endpoint expects the token to be posted to it in encoded or in unencoded form?
I belive that most probably after executing `string token = accessToken.Replace("Bearer ", "");` your `token` variable contains something like this: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`
And if "api/v1/validateToken" expects to see unencoded JSON like this `{"jwtToken": "my token"}` it simply can't handle the data posted....

Comment: @Xiaosu I try using the object and also the object as string, but does not work.

Comment: @jdweng I work remote on a virtual machine from a costumer and he does not allow installing software. Fiddler and co is not available.

Comment: @OleksandrTyshchenko I post the token encrypted, so the endpoint need's it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to authenticate my self at the endpoint, to add the token to the header.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

Now it works. Thanks to everybody!